# What purpose does pausing the auctions serve?

Tags: us20130304599

What is the purpose of pausing auctions and removing bidding interface to chat?

Am I the only one seeing this? But it would be really annoying to be bid on the site because of the constant pausing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Patents. Although you were most likely led here from a "discuss this patent" link from google patents, this site is not for open ended discussion and is also not a way to directly communicate with the inventors. We are set up to post and answer questions about looking for prior art and about the U.S. patent system.

Comment: Thanks George..I am the inventor of a very similar system [link](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130262257). So I know my application is prior art to this.